# Perforce changelist vs individual files

Tags: perforce

What is the main difference between a changelist and submitting changes to individual files? I am used to SVN/GIT idea of submitting changes constantly and reverting if needed on individual files, however this new concept of Changelists is new to me. It looks like so far when I make edits to indiviual files P4 is creating a new change list every time I submit the changes but I also see it as a holder of multiple files that can be submitted (commited/pushed) at once but how do I keep the history of individual file changes?

Pointing me to documentation is acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A changelist collects a group of changes that belong together as a unit.

Perforce still retains the history of each individual file, but it also tracks a set of related changes into a larger unit, called a changelist.

A changelist is used to move you from one consistent state of your files, to the next consistent state.

If you are making related changes to multiple files, for example:

1. You change the signature for some method in a .h header file
2. You change the implementation of that method in the .cc file for that class
3. You change all the callers of that method to call using the new arguments

Then it's very nice to be able to gather all of that work into a single changelist, so that the other people on your team receive all of those changes at once.

Most modern version control systems have this concept, nowadays, but 20 years ago Perforce was rather unusual for featuring it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, using the example you provided say for #1 if I were to make another modification to the signature of such method that would require 2 commits and the history would go along with it. In perforce I see it only as one changelist commit (all files as a group) and the individual history would be lost. That is my current understanding and I may be totally off base.

Comment: You could still do individual submits for each of those if you wanted to, but generally you'd want to do all of those as one (with an appropriate changelist description) so you don't have a case of someone syncing the signature change without also getting the implementation change.

Comment: You can also still look at the history of individual files, which will tell you what changelist each revision belongs to.

Comment: @MikeO'Connor Precisely, that is where things get hairy for me. Based on your comment we would have multiple changelists and I we may not done with the project itself. At one point I was thinking of a changelist almost as a tag where you would have several commits but when you are done with your project you would create a TAG to mark when things are completed.

Comment: You can also create tags in Perforce (see the 'p4 tag' command). They are quite useful, too.

Comment: Thanks @BryanPendleton! I do see you are able to create tags. I was just using tags as an example to explain my train of thought.